# Setting priority for loading slf4j jar from custom path apart from JRE

Tags: jetty, slf4j

Am upgrading jetty 4.2.24 to jetty 9.2.25,i got a dependency with slf4j version for jetty.
jetty 9.2.25 requires slf4j 1.7.5 but am using 1.5.6 version for both jetty web server and JACORB.
the problem am facing here is jetty is taking the jar directly under JVM /ext path, i cant replace the slf4j 1.5.6 under JVM directly since JACORB is using it.
I have searched in web and tried to dynamically exclude the jar, but its only showing with Maven which am not using.

please let me know if there is any way to give some priority for jars under jetty configuration , so that it will not take jar under JVM(slf4j 1.5.6 ) 
and take new jar (slf4j 1.7.5) in some other path.

Comment: Don't use the JVM `/ext` path, its deprecated and unavailable in Java 9+ anyway.   And there is nothing that can be done to override the JVM `/ext` path, it takes precedence over even the JVM classes. (you can even replace the JVM classes that way)

Comment: Also, [Jetty 9.2.x was announced to be EOL (End of Life) back in April 2016](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02726.html).  It officially became unsupported in [Jan 2018](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html), consider upgrading.